# subscription to news letter in drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am new to drupal and creating website. there is requirement to let the user to subscribe to newsletter just submitting their email from index page. no need to crate account for this. I have already installed simple news module. But unable to create a form with single fiels on index page .

Please help me. Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the Webform and Webform Block modules.  Create a webform with an email field and check the checkbox to generate a block for the form.  Next, go to Admin->Build->Block and you'll see a block that corresponds to your form.  You can place it wherever you want.